# How set routing for nested components

Tags: angular, routes

I'm setting routing for my angular website. Below is structure of my components and path name which i want to have on every of this loaded components:

```
/app
   /start-page-container (www.mypage.com)
      /price (www.mypage.com/price)
      /about (www.mypage.com/about)
   /secound-page-container
      /dashboard (www.mypage.com/dashboard)
      /charts (www.mypage.com/charts)
      /tables (www.mypage.com/tables)
```

I don't know how to redirect for specific subpages when my components have different containers and common first part of the path (`www.mypage.com`). I have in my mind two aproach. 
**First**:

```
{path: '', loadChildren: 'app/start-page-container#MyPageModule'},
{path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'app/secound-page-container#SecondPageContainer'}
```

and later (inside each container) second router:

```
{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'charts ', component: ChartsComponent },
{ path: 'tables', component: TablesComponent }
```

But the approach will build path like: `www.mypage.com/dashboard/charts` not like `www.mypage.com/charts`.

**Second approach:**
It's similar to first, but instead `loadChildren` use `children` and load nested componenets, but this approach also create path like above.

Someone know how to set it correctly? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use child modules and just components you can do the following:

At first define your routes similar to the this example

```json
{
  path: '/', component: StartPageContainerComponent, children: [
    { path: 'price', component: PriceComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
  ]
}, {
  path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
    { path: 'charts', component: ChartsComponent }
  ]
}
```

In your app.component's template you can use

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This will display the `StartPageContainerComponent` when navigated to `mypage.com` and the `DashboardComponent`, when navigated to `mypage.com/dashboard`.

In your `StartPageContainerComponent` you can also use the router outlet to display the child routes

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

which will let you display child-routes, e.g. `mypage.com/startPage/price`. The `PriceComponent` will be displayed in the `StartPageContainerComponent`. Implementing the `DashboardComponent` children works analogous.

Routing in combination with modules works a little different. Let me know if you use modules.

Comment: very thanks for your answer. I dont use modules, but i can wraped my componenets to modules if my problem required modules instead components. Your approach not resolve my problem becuase i still have e.g. ```mypage.com/startPage/price``` and ```mypage.com/dashboard/charts```. How i wrote above, I want to have ```mypage.com/price``` and ```mypage.com/charts```. Maybe i should modified structure of my components, becuase is bad. Idk..

Comment: Each `/routeName` targets a specific component. E.g. you can have `/price` targeting *PriceComponent* and so on. You also can have e.g. `/dashboard/price` as a nested route, which targets *Dashboard* having a nested router-outlet targeting *PriceComponent*.